# angular-fullstack: call api without _id, like findByField

Tags: node.js, mongoose, angular-fullstack

I have collection mongodb like this:

```
 var CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
Name: String,
Description: String,
Picture: {
   type: String,
   default: 'http://placehold.it/64x64'},
Level: {
   type: Number,
   default: 1},
Owner:{
  type: Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Category'}
 });
```

How can get result using Owner, because api of this just can get result by _id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    var owner = {ref:'Category};
    category_model.findOne({owner: owner}, 'ref', {lean: true}, function (err, owner) {
    });
```

Comment: thanks you, i will try. but what is 'category_model'

Comment: it's a mongoose model, see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/model-definition.html